# Consulta con LIKE y NATURAL JOIN pero solo me trae un solo registro

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Buenas noches tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT producto.id_producto AS modelo,producto.descripcion_producto AS descripcion,    
mostrar_producto.muestra as stock,marca.nombre_marca AS marca,
producto.ubicacion_almacen AS ubicacion,p_unitario.id_tipo_moneda AS p_moneda,
p_unitario.precio AS precio,c_compra.id_tipo_moneda AS c_moneda, c_compra.costo AS costo 
FROM producto NATURAL JOIN mostrar_producto NATURAL JOIN p_unitario 
NATURAL JOIN c_compra NATURAL JOIN marca  
WHERE producto.id_producto LIKE '%12345%' OR producto.descripcion_producto LIKE '%12345%'
```

Y me da este resultado:
[image: Resultado de la consulta]

Pero estos son los datos registrados:
[image: Tabla producto]

[image: Tabla c_compra]

[image: Tabla p_unitario]

[image: Tabla mostrar_producto]

Al usar solo con JOIN da el siguiente resultado:

```
SELECT producto.id_producto AS modelo,producto.descripcion_producto AS descripcion,
mostrar_producto.muestra as stock,marca.nombre_marca AS marca,
producto.ubicacion_almacen AS ubicacion,p_unitario.id_tipo_moneda AS p_moneda,
p_unitario.precio AS precio,c_compra.id_tipo_moneda AS c_moneda, c_compra.costo AS costo 
FROM producto JOIN mostrar_producto JOIN p_unitario JOIN c_compra JOIN marca  
WHERE producto.id_producto LIKE '%12345%' OR producto.descripcion_producto LIKE '%12345%'
```

[image: Resultado de la consulta con JOIN]

Me trae todos los registros que coinciden pero repetidamente, no se porque solo me trae un solo dato.

Comment: algun experto en mysql te lo va a poder explicar mejor, pero tenes varios problemas con los join y la precedencia de los mismos y por eso los resultados raros..

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, es más útil poner texto con estructuras y datos de tablas que imágenes. En cuanto al problema en sí: `NATURAL JOIN` no es una práctica recomendada porque entre otras cosas oscurece las relaciones entre tablas. . Yo escribiría la consulta con `JOIN` normal, sólo que en la 2ª forma no especificas cuáles son las columnas de la relación:  `SELECT producto.id_producto ... 
FROM producto JOIN segunda-tabla ON producto.columna = segunda-tabla.columna JOIN tabla-3 ON ... etc ... 
WHERE producto.id_producto LIKE '%12345%' OR producto.descripcion_producto LIKE '%12345%'`

Comment: Exactamente que deseas que te muestre tu consulta?